# Converting string into Date() in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, date

How do I convert this timestamp from php into a javascript Date() object?

This is how I grab the time:

`$timestart = time();`

and I parse this to a javascript function and I want to convert it into a JavaScript date object.

help, all this date stuff confuses me quite a bit.

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: generic JS implementations are required to understand RFC-1123 datetime strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `val` contains your [PHP value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) which is

> the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch

then you just need this:

```
var timestart = new Date(val * 1000);
```

JavaScript uses the same base time as UNIX systems (midnight on 01/01/1970) but measured in milliseconds rather than seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Solution here :
[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Substring the parts of the timestamp you need to create the Date. Then initialise like so,

```
var d = new Date(year, month, date);
```

This is a cross browser implementation.